# jasper report: custom columns on crosstab

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

i would like to know if there is a way to set a custom column after the totals column that give me the crosstab.

I need to print dinamic columns, and the total of them, and add some information at the end but can`t find the way to add custom information after the total column...

did anyone tried to do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding a top level column group with a constant expression, setting the group header height to 0 and using the group total column to display the additional values.  The values could be passed as a measure with `calculation="Nothing"`, or via other means depending on the particular case.

Here's an report that implements my suggestion.  It's a modified JasperReports sample report, you can run it with the sample DB in Jaspersoft Studio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ProductsReport" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="782" leftMargin="30" rightMargin="30" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" uuid="d8258224-60b6-4c49-b0e9-a411ee2fbd39">
    <style name="Sans_Normal" isDefault="true" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
    <style name="Sans_Bold" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="8" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
    <style name="cell">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Customer_Quantity" uuid="d7fa233d-253a-4620-93b5-d8c430099436">
        <parameter name="CityParam" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[SELECT product.name, positions.quantity,
                       address.firstname, address.lastname, address.street
                FROM product, positions, address, document
                WHERE product.id = positions.productid AND
                      address.id = document.addressid AND
                      document.id = positions.documentid AND
                      address.city=$P{CityParam}]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Quantity" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="FirstName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="LastName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="street" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <title>
        <band height="70">
            <crosstab isRepeatColumnHeaders="false">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="782" height="70" uuid="d3aca7c7-1165-4cb5-a7ca-e67b01a5b15d"/>
                <crosstabDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="Customer_Quantity" uuid="69151f6b-5c48-4d23-b978-e8fdfbf7b631">
                            <datasetParameter name="CityParam">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA["Seattle"]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                </crosstabDataset>
                <rowGroup name="NameGroup" width="80" totalPosition="None">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{FirstName} + " " + $F{LastName}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents style="cell">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="Sans_Bold" x="5" y="0" width="75" height="10" uuid="7f161b84-95ad-4ce4-b619-dfdabb44899e"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{NameGroup}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup height="0" name="dummy" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[""]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents style="cell">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement style="Sans_Bold" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="50"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Street]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <columnGroup name="ProductGroup" height="50" totalPosition="End" headerPosition="Stretch">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents style="cell">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="Sans_Bold" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="50" uuid="2af151be-c117-41c0-864d-279ef72186ec"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="Left"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ProductGroup}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#FFFF60" mode="Opaque" style="cell">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement style="Sans_Bold" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="50" uuid="036e9415-01db-4725-8eeb-467f4ae992ab"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[TOTAL]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="QuantityMesure" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{Quantity}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <measure name="street" class="java.lang.String" calculation="Nothing">
                    <measureExpression>$F{street}</measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="20" height="10">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#FFFFFF" mode="Opaque" style="cell">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="20" height="10" uuid="ee3abbdf-bec7-4b0f-9d5a-7ed46e897fd0"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{QuantityMesure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="30" height="10" columnTotalGroup="ProductGroup">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#FFFF60" mode="Opaque" style="cell">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="10" uuid="6747a993-1322-4432-ad74-dbbec94ee758"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{QuantityMesure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="80" height="10" columnTotalGroup="dummy">
                    <cellContents style="cell">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="10"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{street}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```